# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Question: [Hacked aiming xgirlfreind](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201807/hacked-aiming-xgirlfreind)

The answer was deleted by a moderator, but I do not understand why. It has some humour/sarcasm, but it does make an attempt at answering the question. I doubt the question will ever be edited sufficiently to be reopened, but in case someone does come across it, why not leave the answer?

I would vote to undelete and let a vote decide (or however that works), but [once again](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3115/this-answer-was-edited-and-should-be-undeleted-i-cannot-vote-to-undelete), I can't because it was deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 7):

The question was not a question, and was closed accordingly.

The person who wrote the "answer" admitted it was not an answer and posted anyway, which they really should not have done. There is no point writing an answer to a question that does not exist. The answer may have been appropriate on another question but not here.